# django url regex to match optional parameters

Tags: regex, django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I need a regex that should match the following strings:

- users/24
- users/24/
- users/24/sam
- users/24/sam/
- users/24/sam/tab_name
- users/24/sam/tab_name/

where, ***pk=24, username=sam, tab=tab_name***

So far I have a url as:

```
url(r'^users/(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<username>[-\w\d]+)?/?(?P<tab>[-\w\d]+)?/?', vw.ProfileView.as_view(), name='profile')
```

The above url matches everything above. But while using

`{% url 'profile' pk=24 username="sam" tab="tab_name" %}`

the output is : *users/samtab_name*

I know the problem here i.e, `/?` optional slash. But I don't want it to be optional when using `{% url 'profile' pk=24 username="sam" tab="tab_name" %}`

Help me with this.

Comment: Try [`^users/(?P<pk>\d+)(?:/(?P<username>[-\w]+))?(?:/(?P<tab>[-\w]+))?/?`](https://regex101.com/r/TIKklT/1). Not sure you need the last `/?` though.

Comment: I suggest you make the slash required (use `/` instead of `/?`). Then the default Django behaviour will be to redirect to the URLs with the slash (e.g. `/users/24/sam` -> `/users/24/sam/`). See the docs on [`append_slash`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#append-slash) for more info.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your  regex did the work though. I would appreciate if you explained `?:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may make your `/` obligatory by placing them together with the named capturing groups inside optional [non-capturing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do):

```
^users/(?P<pk>\d+)(?:/(?P<username>[-\w]+))?(?:/(?P<tab>[-\w]+))?/?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TIKklT/1).

Note that `\w` already matches digits, so you do not need `\d` inside the character classes.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `users/` - a literal substring
- `(?P<pk>\d+)` - a named capturing group "pk" matching 1+ digtis
- `(?:/(?P<username>[-\w]+))?` - an optional non-capturing group (there is `?` quantifier after the closing `)`) matching

  - `/` - a `/` char
  - `(?P<username>[-\w]+)` - Group "username": 1+ word or `-` chars
- `(?:/(?P<tab>[-\w]+))?` - an optional non-capturing group matching

  - `/` - a `/` char
  - `(?P<tab>[-\w]+)` - Group "tab": 1+ word or `-` chars
- `/?` - an optional `/` char.